Morse functions generate non-degenerate Hamiltonian flow
Let $(M, \omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold. A (time-independent) Hamiltonian $H: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is called non-degenerate, if for every time-1 orbit, i.e. $x \in M$ with $\phi^H_1(x) = x$, the matrix $d\phi^H_1(x)$ does not have eigenvalue 1.
I know how to prove that if $H$ is non-degenerate, it is a Morse funtion. We were told in class that the converse holds under the assumption that $H$ is $C^1$-small.
Is this converse true? How do I see it? (Is $C^2$-small maybe needed instead, in order to guarantee that $H$ has only constant time-1 orbits?)

In the $C^2$ small case you have the proof in "Morse Theory and Floer Homology" by Michèle Audin and Mihai Damian (Proposition 6.1.5 and 6.1.6).
The essensce of the argument is the estimate
$$
\| z'\|_{L_2} \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \|z''\|_{L_2}
$$
where $z:\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a loop in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. On the other hand, if $\|D X_H\|_{L^2} < 2\pi$ you get (if $z$ is non-constant):
$$
\|z''\|_{L^2} < 2\pi \|z'\|
$$
which is a contradiction. This local estimate can be translated to closed manifolds by looking into sufficiently nice open cover.
I am not sure what is true in the case of $C^1$ small Hamiltonian. My guess would be that one can construct a $C^1$ small Hamiltonian which has non-constant 1-periodic orbit. Some naive intuition behind it is that $C^1$ size determines the speed of a curve (or length of a closed orbit), but $C^2$ size determines the curvature. You might construct Hamiltonians so that speed is very small, but curvature is very large, so it can close up in short time.

There are arbitrarily $C^1$-small Morse functions that are degenerate. The basic idea is that expressed by Filip Broćić: although the speed of a (nonconstant) of the orbit of a point $x$ under the Hamiltonian flow $\phi^H_t$ of a Hamiltonian $H$ is 'controlled' by the $C^1$-size of $H$, it is possible that the path loops at $t = 1$ (in such a way that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $d\phi^H_1(x)$) if the 'radius' of the loop is small.
Let's sketch some examples for $M = S^2$ the unit round sphere equipped with its standard area form $\omega$. Note that the function $H(x,y,z) = 2 \pi z$ (where $(x,y,z \in S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$) is a Morse function with critical points $(0, 0, \pm 1)$; this is best seen using the coordinates $(x,y)$ to chart $M$ near the critical points, as $H(x,y) = \pm 2\pi \sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2)} \approx \pm 2\pi (1 - (x^2+y^2)/2)$ near $(0, 0, \pm 1)$, respectively. Note that $\phi^{H}_t$ is a rotation around the vertical axis of $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ by an angle of $t$ radians; in particular for $t=1$, we have $\phi^{H}_1 = Id$, so $H$ is degenerate.
Or course, $H$ is not $C^1$-small, but 'it is' near its critical points; so the idea is to replace $H$ by a function that is almost constant away from its critical points, but essentially 'equal' (up to addition by a local constant function) near the critical points.
More concretely, for $\epsilon > 0$, consider your favorite smooth function $\chi_{\epsilon} : [-1,1] \to [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ such that:

$\chi'_{\epsilon} > 0$ over the whole of $[-1,1]$, and

$\chi_{\epsilon}'(z) = 1$ for $z \in [-1, -1 + \epsilon/2] \cup [1- \epsilon/2, 1]$.


Then set $H_{\epsilon} : M \to \mathbb{R}^2$ to be $H_{\epsilon}(x,y,z) = 2 \pi \chi_{\epsilon}(z)$. This is a Morse function with only critical points being $(0,0,\pm 1)$. Near any of these critical points $H_{\epsilon}$ equals $H + \mbox{constant}$; hence $\phi^{H_{\epsilon}}_1 = Id$ in neighborhoords of the critical points and so $H_{\epsilon}$ is degenerate. Moreover, the $C^1$-norm of $H_{\epsilon}$ is bounded from above by $C \epsilon$ for some constant $C$: this is not entirely obvious since $\chi_{\epsilon}$ has derivative equal to $1$ for $|z| \approx 1$, but one needs to keep in mind that $z$, as a function on $M$, has derivative zero at the points $(0,0, \pm 1)$ and thus small derivatives in small neighborhoods of those points.
Since $\epsilon$ can be taken arbitrarily small, this proves that there are arbitrarily $C^1$-small degenerate Morse functions on the sphere.
Note that the above functions $H_{\epsilon}$ are not $C^2$-small, since $\chi_{\epsilon}$ is not ($\chi'_{\epsilon}$ quickly varies from $1$ to $0$).
As explained by Filip, sufficiently $C^2$-small Morse functions are non-degenerate: (very) roughly speaking, since the Hamiltonian field $X_H$ is (up to a 90° rotation) the gradient of $H$, the Hessian of $H$ is essentially the derivative $DX_H$ of $X_H$. On a compact manifold, $X_H$ vanishes somewhere; hence, if $DX_H$ is small everywhere, $X_H$ is small everywhere. But $X_H$ being the speed of the Hamiltonian orbits, this implies that the orbits move slowly and curve slowly: a detailed analysis shows that non-constant orbits can only loop for $t>1$. And if the Hessian is even smaller, then the linearized flow $d\phi^H_t$ at the critical points also has no nontrivial loop.
